# Регулярное выражение, исключающее один вариант набора символов в скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Простите за кривой заголовок, не смог правильно сформулировать.

Дано: есть выражение

```
^(([^/\.])+)/?$
```

которое находит последовательность из символов, среди которых нет слешей и точки. Всё просто.

Задача: добавить в эту регулярку кусок, чтобы, если кусок в скобках был равен слову (например, "test"), то оно не походило бы.

Например:

```
word
123
и это тоже
```

все эти подходят, но

```
test
```

не подходил бы.

у меня самого не получилось его создать, прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то так:

```
(?(?=.*\btest\b|.*\..*|.*/.*)^$|^.*$)
```

Comment: а как это совместить с [^/\.] ?

Comment: немного до-подкрутил. И вот живой пример http://regexr.com?37kji